# how to save folder out of computer

Tags: upgrade

I'm on standard Ubuntu and have a folder with 16 videos. Am having issues in upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 (step 2 will be upgrade to 20.04 next). Have been told to go in 2
steps which sounds reasonable to me. Having trouble upgrading I'm thinking of putting in
20.04 with a fresh disc which would lose my folder. I think. That is how I've done it before, not having had success with upgrading. Is there some way to save those videos
out of the machine? Some are too big to put on a DVD separately. I'm not too adept with
computer tricks as I'm a latecomer to this game. Thanks, Al

Comment: USB sticks are relatively inexpensive solutions for this sort of problem 

Comment: I would recommend to complete your upgrade process. Please post output of `lsb_release -a` `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt --include="*.list"` (if long - use pastebin).

Comment: Still, if there are no copies of these video's elsewhere, they probably are of little value.

Comment: I don't know how I did it but I did stumble onto the upgrade. Now on 20.04